# Google Sheets: How to combine 2 ranges in 1 column

Tags: google-sheets

I am looking for a way to combine 2 / potentially more columns into 1 column, where all values (text) of the source columns are combined with each other (covering all possible combinations of the values from the 2 columns):

| Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Value 1a | Value 2a | Value 1a + Value 2a |
| Value 1b | Value 2b | Value 1b + Value 2a |
| Value 1c | Value 2c | Value 1c + Value 2a |
|  |  | Value 1a + Value 2b |
|  |  | Value 1b + Value 2b |
|  |  | Value 1c + Value 2b |
|  |  | Value 1a + Value 2c |
|  |  | Value 1b + Value 2c |
|  |  | Value 1c + Value 2c |

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) like the one you describe with string concatenation like this:

`=arrayformula( flatten( transpose(A2:A4) & " " & B2:B4 ) )`